# Burn subtitle in youtube video while downloading

Tags: youtube-dl, yt-dlp

How to burn a YouTube video with a subtitle while downloading (simultaneously) using yt-dlp and ffmpeg. Can you help me with a batch file or command line syntax?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code/homework writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code/calculations you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59303838/how-to-burn-hardcode-subtitle-to-the-downloaded-youtube-video-with-youtube-dl

Comment: HI, I tried with below syntax and there thrown is shown as well.

Comment: yt-dlp -f "[height=720][ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]" --write-sub --write-auto-sub --embed-subs --exec "mkdir temp && ffmpeg -i {} -vf subtitles={}:force_style='FontName=Arial' -acodec copy temp/{} && mv -f temp/{} {} && rm -r temp" --restrict-filenames https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhNOHzcqh2w

Comment: Error: 
A subdirectory or file temp already exists.
ERROR: Postprocessing: Command returned error code 1